# Duda sobre herencia y llamada a funciones en clase base

Tags: c++, qt

La duda me ha venido por Qt, pero es de C++.

Si tengo una estructura de clases como ésta: (solo defino `eventFilter`)

```
class DelegadoBase : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit DelegadoBase(QObject* parent=nullptr);
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent* event);
};
```

Y esta clase derivada:

```
class DelegadoEditorNumeros : public DelegadoBase
{
public:
    explicit DelegadoEditorNumeros(QObject* parent=nullptr);
    QWidget * createEditor(QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem&option, const QModelIndex&index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex&index)const;
    void setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex&index) const;
    void paint( QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
    QSize sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
    QString displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale) const;

private:
    QRegExp* rx;
};
```

En el método `paint()` de la clase derivada, cuando llamo al método de la clase base, se supone que debería de llamar al método `paint()` de `DelegadoBase`, y que éste llame al método `paint()` de `QStyledItemDelegate`, pero al no estar definido en `DelegadoBase` me entra la duda de cómo sería lo correcto.

Sería algo así:

```
void DelegadoEditorNumeros::paint( QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{ 
if (condicion)
    {              
        haz las cosas asi
    else
    {
        DelegadoBase::paint(painter, option, index);//así
        //QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);o así
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el momento en el que, en una clase, se declara un método como `virtual`, se crea una tabla de punteros a funciones asociada a la clase. En esta tabla se almacenan las llamadas redeclaradas en cada clase derivada.

Si una función no está redeclarada en la clase *padre* pero sí en la clase *abuelo*, no pasa absolutamente nada, el compilador consultará la citada tabla y llamará a la primera función disponible:

- Si la función se redeclara en el *padre* se llamará a la misma.
- Si no está declarada en el *padre* pero sí en el *abuelo* se llamará a la del abuelo
- Si no está declarada en el *abuelo* pero sí en el *bisabuelo* ...

Igualmente, puedes saltarte la implementación del padre llamando directamente a `Abuelo::funcion()`.

Un ejemplo práctico:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void func1()
  { std::cout << "A::func1()\n"; }

  virtual void func2()
  { std::cout << "A::func2()\n"; }

  virtual void func3()
  { std::cout << "A::func3()\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  void func1() override
  { std::cout << "B::func1()\n"; }

  void func3() override
  { std::cout << "B::func3()\n"; }
};

struct C : B
{
  void func1() override
  {
    std::cout << "C::func1()\n";
    B::func1(); // Llama a la funcion del padre -> existe
  }

  void func2() override
  {
    std::cout << "C::func2()\n";
    B::func2(); // Llama a la funcion del padre -> no existe
  }

  void func3() override
  {
    std::cout << "C::func3()\n";
    A::func3(); // Llama directamente a la funcion del abuelo
  }
};
```

Puedes verlo funcionando <kbd>[aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ByYj6NJqUKN10epa)</kbd>